# Limit choices on model to self reference

Tags: django

I have a model that has a recursive reference to itself.

```
class Section(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', limit_choices_to= ... )
```

Is there a way I can limit the parent choices to sections that belong to the same report?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this in a ModelForm, but I have NOT tested this code.

```
class SectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Section

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['parent'].queryset = self._meta.model.objects.filter(
                report=self.instance.report)
```

Comment: Should't `super`s first argument be `SectionForm`?

Comment: @florisla Good catch. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a custom validator?

Check if the new `pk` is part of the subset you require, otherwise raise a `ValidationError`.